# Retrieve node value from XML response in SOAPUI which contains CDATA tag

Tags: xml, xpath, soapui, cdata

I am trying to retrieve the Atomic Number using `Xpath` from the below xml SoapUI response

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <soap:Body>
      <GetAtomicNumberResponse xmlns="http://www.webserviceX.NET">
         <GetAtomicNumberResult><![CDATA[<NewDataSet>
  <Table>
    <AtomicNumber>47</AtomicNumber>
    <ElementName>Silver</ElementName>
    <Symbol>Ag</Symbol>
    <AtomicWeight>107.87</AtomicWeight>
    <BoilingPoint>2485</BoilingPoint>
    <IonisationPotential>7.58</IonisationPotential>
    <EletroNegativity>1.42</EletroNegativity>
    <AtomicRadius>1.34</AtomicRadius>
    <MeltingPoint>1235</MeltingPoint>
    <Density>10490</Density>
  </Table>
</NewDataSet>]]></GetAtomicNumberResult>
      </GetAtomicNumberResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

have tried the below one

```
declare namespace ns2='http://www.webserviceX.NET';
//ns2:GetAtomicNumberResponse[1]/ns2:GetAtomicNumberResult[1]
```

am getting all the data starting from `[<NewDataset> .... </NewDataSet>]`, but I just need `<AtomicNumber>` value.

Comment: If all else fails, try the documentation: http://www.soapui.org/Functional-Testing/working-with-cdata.html

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is that `CDATA` is treated as string inside an *Xml* and when working as a *XPath*; so if you want to access a node inside `CDATA` using *XPath* you need first to make the path to access `CDATA` and a way to parse its content as an *Xml*.

Hopefully *SOAPUI* use *Saxon*, and *Saxon* contains the follow function [`saxon:parse`](http://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation/functions/saxon/parse.html) which allows to parse the string content returned from *XPath* as a *Xml*.

Note that *Saxon* version 9.3 replace this function for [`saxon:parse-xml`](http://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation/functions/fn/parse-xml.html) however in *SOAPUI* is not accessible since it use *saxon* version 9.1.8.

So in your *Property transfer* testStep you can use the follow *XPath*:

```
declare namespace ns2='http://www.webserviceX.NET';
(saxon:parse(//ns2:GetAtomicNumberResponse[1]/ns2:GetAtomicNumberResult[1]))//*:AtomicNumber
```

Or in a shorter *SOAPUI* way:

```
(saxon:parse(//*:GetAtomicNumberResponse/*:GetAtomicNumberResult))//*:AtomicNumber
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
def respXmlHolder = new XmlHolder(testRunner.testCase.testSteps["GetAtomicNumber"].testRequest.response.getContentAsXml());

respXmlHolder.namespaces["ns"] = "http://www.webserviceX.NET";

def CDATAXml = respXmlHolder.getNodeValue("//ns:GetAtomicNumberResponse/ns:GetAtomicNumberResult");

log.info CDATAXml;

def CDATAXmlHolder = new XmlHolder(CDATAXml);

def atomicNumber=CDATAXmlHolder.getNodeValue("//NewDataSet/Table/AtomicNumber");

com.eviware.soapui.support.UISupport.showInfoMessage("Atomic Number:-"+atomicNumber);

log.info "Atomic Number:-"+atomicNumber
```

Comment: Add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue

Answer (score -4):

c#

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("XMLFile1.xml");
var result = doc.Descendants(XNamespace.Get("http://www.webserviceX.NET")+"AtomicNumber")
                .First();
```

Comment: Unfortunately SoapUI does not understand C#. And further, the element the OP is asking for is inside of a CDATA block.